# ImportError: blis.cy does not export expected C function sgemm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, spacy, anaconda3

I have installed spacy in my anaconda prompt using

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

but, when i try to import in jupyter notebook :
import spacy
the result is like this:

```
**ImportError: blis.cy does not export expected C function sgemm**
```

please how to solve this?

i tried to reinstall but still no progress